# A circuit similar in working to a NOTC relay?

Tags: relay, timer, circuit-design, solid-state-relay

How do I build a circuit that gives out a "high" only when given in a "high" continuously for a preset time period? The input is actually the out from a logic gate.

The following details have been added considering the suggestions from Andy Aka. 
The rate at which the output goes from high to low once the input is low, need not be fast and a delay up to a few seconds is tolerable. Also if the input is not high long enough to set the output high, the timer should be reset, which could also be non-spontaneous and could take up to a few seconds.

Comment: How quickly should the output revert to low when the input goes low? Note that the answer you have accepted may not achieve what you want once you have thought about this. Also, during the high being present, but the output not yet gone high, should the occasion of a low reset this time period thus forcing the time period to start over again once the high returns? Think about what you are asking.

Comment: @Andyaka One thing I missed in my details is that the input is actually the out of a logic gate and hence all the issues that you have mentioned are absent. The out goes low as soon as the in goes low. In the occasion of a low before the output goes high, the timer is reset and that's how I want it to be. This circuit is for responding to only a clear, clean signal originating from an environment with lots of noise. Guess I should have added that in the details.

Comment: How can the circuit in the answer you accepted fulfill what you have just told me. How can its output go low as soon as the input goes low. How can the charging of the capacitor reset when input goes low briefly? Please explain how the circuit you have accepted meets with your requirements.

Comment: @Andyaka The circuit in the answer I accepted doesn't work the way I want it to with the discharging resistor R4 and if the input is either high or nothing. But as my input is either high or low, the discharging resistor can be omitted since the low from the input neutralizes the positive charge on the capacitor plate to which it is connected, almost instantly. I had tried out the circuit first and I accepted it because it suited my need.

Comment: My observation has nothing to do with the discharging resistor. If C1 takes time to charge due to R1 then it will also take time to discharge and not reset near-instantly. Your question is under-constrained and makes a bad question in this respect. I'm trying to get you to make your question better.

Comment: @Andyaka Alright. So C1 gets charged through R1 and if the positive voltage at one end of R1 is suddenly taken away,the capacitor will take some time to discharge itself. But what if the positive voltage at R1 is suddenly replaced with a negative voltage (I know that "positive" and "negative" voltages are bad terminologies but I am trying to relate it with "high" and "low") ? Don't you think the capacitor is shorted and would discharge really fast ? " Near-instantly " would be an overstatement. It's fast enough for ordinary uses that doesn't involve high speed data transmission or anything.

Comment: @Andyaka About the question. Even I think it could use a bit more details. It's just that my application isn't that high end and hence could tolerate even if the capacitor took a few seconds to discharge. I was looking for a quick solution and really didn't care about these factors.BTW, to get the required time constant, I used a small capacitor and a large resistor. That could be one reason why it discharges this fast.

Comment: It's just as much about writing good questions for posterity as it is about you getting quick answers.

Comment: @Andyaka I will keep that in mind. I've added a few more details in this question. Thanks!

Comment: You have added the detail about the timer being reset but you have accepted an answer (and I'm aware I'm saying this again) that does not do this - it will charge and discharge at the same exponential rate. I have tried to help you on this but I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: @Andyaka I cannot discard that answer as it really helped me. Hence, I've edited my question to fit the answer.

Comment: So now you have compounded the problem by making my comment below the dubiously accepted answer as if I we're not able to read your question correctly. If I were you I'd consider deleting  this question and learn to think first.

Comment: @Andyaka I am not deleting anything. I needed help, I asked for it and I got it. I didn't add a lot of details into the question since it didn't matter to me much. I've tried my best to fix this for the "posterity" and I am done.

Comment: @Andyaka I've also edited the question to clearly state that the details have been added after having the above conversation with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RC circuit followed by a comparator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f19bbE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 and R3 form a voltage divider and create a reference for the comparator. The voltage at this reference point is

$$V_{ref} = V_{cc} * \frac{R3}{R2 + R3}$$

When the input to the non inverting (+) terminal of the comparator is less than the reference, the output signal will be low. As soon as the input to the + terminal goes above the reference, the output signal will be high.

R1 and C1 form a traditional RC circuit. The voltage on the capacitor Vc is given by 
$$V_c = V_{cc}(1 - e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})$$

To compute the required values for R and C, we set the voltage across the capacitor to be equal to our reference voltage.

$$V_{ref} = V_{c}$$
$$V_{cc} * \frac{R3}{R2 + R3} = V_{cc}(1 - e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})$$

Where we set t equal to our required delay in seconds. We then either choose a fixed value for R or a fixed value for C and solve the equation for the desired unknown.

As an example, let $$R1 = R2$$ so that $$V_{ref} = 0.5V_{cc}$$ We then have $$1 - e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} = 0.5$$

Lets fix t to be 1 second $$1 - e^{\frac{-1}{RC}} = 0.5$$ $$e^{\frac{-1}{RC}} = 0.5$$ $$RC = 1.44$$ We can then either fix a value for R or fix a value for C and compute the unknown. Lets fix R = 1k then $$C = \frac{1.44}{1000}$$ $$C = 1.44mF$$

R4 is optional but it is there to provide a path for the capacitor to discharge after being charged. You can calculate the value of R by determining how quickly you want the voltage to drop.

Also note that the charging of C1 through R1 may load down your input signal. If the input signal is a high impedance signal, consider adding a buffer between the input and R1. This will allow R1 to charge C1 as expected.

Comment: Should the "delay" be reset if while the positive voltage is applied, it returns to 0V for a short period? The OP indicates it should despite accepting this answer.

Comment: This circuit is acceptable with a minor tweak. Ditch the discharging capacitor as the logic out will take care of that (as it is it's optional). It is fine for a quick and dirty solution as it depends on the exponential charging and discharging of a capacitor which could bring in delays where you might not want it.